# ant is looking for location from within location

Tags: java, maven, ant

I'm building a java web application. And I have to do things a certain way as directed by instructions.

When I type "ant deploy" to build a war file, it fails. It says `the file can't be found.`

But it is obviously looking in the wrong place. It says...

> C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\springapp\springapp\C:Program
>   FilesApacheapache-maven-3.0.4-binapache-maven-3.0.4\boot does not
>   exist

Of course that doesn't exist! But I can't find why it thinks that is the valid location. It looks like it is tacking the location that it is looking for - at the end of the current directory. But I can't change directories, because if I do, it then can't find the build.xml file that it needs.

I have ant, maven, and tomcat for this project.

I have a system variable location set for each `TOMCAT_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME`.

The build.properties file in the project file has maven.home set as the correct location.

How can I change where it is looking for that file?

Answer (score 0):

> The build.properties file in the project file has maven.home set as the correct location.

From the look of that path I suspect your `build.properties` contains something like

```
maven.home=C:\Program Files\Apache\....
```

Backslash is an escape character in properties files so you need to either use forward slashes instead of backslashes or double them up.  You should also escape the colon

```
maven.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Apache\\....
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer might have worked, but I just found another answer. Will post for future reference.

Comment: @user1279569 can you post the other solution that worked for you?